# Two Server Apps on one machine

Tags: server, port

Is it possible to run two book server apps on one machine? I have Calibre running successfully on port 80, but I would like to also run Alfa ebooks manager on the same machine. One is great for ebooks and the other is better with audiobooks. I don't know how to run them both so I can access both on my home network.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [su] as it is not about programming. Check if either one of those programs has the option to change ports.

Comment: maybe its affect performance of your apps but it depend upon resources if you have enough resources then you can

Comment: Each port can be used by only one app. If those two are totally independent apps, you can't run them both using the same port, but you could try to configure one app to use a different port. You could also create a reverse-proxy which listens on port 80 and configure your apps both on different port, and the reverse proxy forwards each request to the respective app. But that's beyond the scope of stackoverflow.